# Upload Image to DB by Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload image from my folders to DB by PHPMyAdmin using laravel

inside ProductController.php the store method:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
     {
      Product::create($request->all());
      $formInput=$request->except('ImgSource');

   //        validation
         $this->validate($request,[
             'Name'=>'required',
             'Price'=>'required',
             'type'=>'required',
             'ImgSource'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000',
         ]);
   //        image upload
         $image=$request->file('ImgSource');
         if($image){
             $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
             $image->move('images',$imageName);

             $formInput['ImgSource']=$imageName;

         }

         Product::create($formInput);
         return redirect()->route('product.index');
     }
```

and in the web.php

Route::resource('product','ProductsController');
 and I use the form in create.blade.php

```
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('ImgSource', 'Image') }}
            {{ Form::file('ImgSource',array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
```

It stores in the table products as
C:\xampp\xampp1\tmp\php46F9.tmp
what should I do to add correct images?